# Struts 2 Framework getting data from database and display on a jsp (with ajax calling the output of the display.jsp)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

In Struts 2 framework, is it ok if I would have this kind of codes:

**`display.jsp`**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"/>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <%
         try {
             // sql statements here (SELECT Statements / PreparedStatement)
             // .... ResultSet
         }
         catch (Exception e) {}
    %>
    <s:property value=""/> <!-- data/results from database -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Because my goal is to display the data from database when the page is viewed. `display.jsp` should display the information from the database.

I know it should execute any `Action` classes because of the Struts 2 Framework. But what I know about Struts2 is that you need a form to be submitted or a button to be submitted to execute the `Action` classes.

But the user should not submit or click anything, and that `display.jsp` should display information from the database.

I am thinking whether if there is a way to execute an `Action` class. But `<s:action name=''/>` is not just working. So I would be forced to place `<% %>` (scriplets) on the jsp page.

Because `display.jsp` page is not going to be visited by the user directly. I will use this page for `AJAX` outputs.

Like for example:

```
    <div id="ajaxOutput"></div>
    <script>
        $( '#ajaxOutput' ).load( 'display.jsp' );
    </script>
```

From there, I will display the data / results in `display.jsp` to that specific `<div>`
 
Because if I do that `AJAX` `JQUERY` `.load()` it will just be a blank page because If there is no codes in the jsp page to get information from the database and display it.

It's so hard to explain, I hope you guys get it.

Comment: Call an action not jsp directly in `load`.

Comment: `$( '#ajaxOutput' ).load( 'some_action' );`

Comment: when I do that, will the `Action` class refer the `<result>` for output? Like `<result>display.jsp</result>` ?

If I used that codes, the `console` of the browser is so annoying, it will just tell that `localhost:8080/some_action' NOT FOUND.

Comment: Do you have this action? Use `<s:url>` tag to create action url.

Comment: how is this `<s:url>` work?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/url.html.

Comment: is `%{somevalue}` is equivalent to `request.getParameter("somevalue")` ?

Comment: Antipattern warning. Just call an Action, then return a JSP snippet. KISS paradigm FTW.

Comment: is using `request.getParameter()` or `session.getParameter()` inside jsp scriplet also an antipattern in struts 2?

Comment: @user2975385 It's antipattern in JSP, scriptlets should be avoided.

Comment: @AleksandrM the `<s:url>` wont work. it doesnt execute the `action`

Comment: @RomanC how about using the `${some_value }` in .jsp using struts2 framework? is it antipattern?

Comment: @user2975385 Struts2 is based on servlet technology, how do you think is it antipattern in servlets?

Comment: @user2975385 JSP EL is the preferred method for accessing values. `<s:url>` doesn't execute actions, it creates URLs for them.

Comment: @RomanC you said scriplets should be avoided, then if I have a code (in JSP page) like `<% if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) { response.sendRedirect("login.jsp"); return; } %>` then it is antipattern?

Also, using directives like `<%@ page import %>`, `<%@ taglib %>`, `<%@ include file %>` is not an antipattern in struts right?

Comment: @user2975385 As I said scriptlets (<%%>) are highly discouraged if you use it for writing code in JSP. Write a code in the action. JSP directives you can write it's not a scriptlets. JSP expressions you can also write. But if you are programming Struts you can use OGNL instead.

Comment: because I want to implement my `<% if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) { response.sendRedirect("login.jsp"); return; } %>` in struts2, i just can't find how to do that in struts 2

Answer (score 0):

First of all , there is no need to submit a form or button to execute an action class in struts2. You can use any of the actions mapped in the struts.xml for this purpose. The action can be triggered in an asynchronous way by use of ajax and json. I have once used a method

`getJSON()`,
 which will have 3 parameters , first is the name of action mapped in struts.xml, second parameter will be the input to action , you can use `.serialize()` method to pass the input , and the third parameter will have the output as aJSON object.The following result type needed for that in the struts.xml.

```
 <result type="json" />
```

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/

Comment: do you know how ajax works in struts 2? in this situation: example a user1 sent a message (chat) to user2, then when the message is inserted in the database, the website should notify the user2 the he has a message received from user1. My problem is that you have to refresh the whole page just to know if someone had messaged you.

Comment: I dont know, is that the right way  to deal with chatting apps in java, but surely you can just refresh that particular area where yo are expecting the message( can be a <DIV> ), and with the refresh you can call the server  via AJAX , ie like getJSON() , so that you will get the response with out any page refresh..